# Как выбрать линукс при загрузке ос?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

на диске С установлена windows 10 в нем же разделил диск, сделал новый раздел и на него установил linux теперь не знаю как сделать чтоб при включении пк был выбор операционной системы

Answer (score 1):

Настроить GRUB, установленный на раздел с Линуксом, и в BIOS/EFI выбрать загрузку с этого раздела.
Или:
Установить и настроить GRUB4DOS на раздел с Windows. И настроить его, вписав туда обе ОС.

Выбирайте способ. Первый на мой взгляд лучше.

Comment: А как Вы установили люних. НЕ настраивая *grub*?! Вообще-то, при установке люниха, установщик должен был выдать Вам нечто вроде: "Обнаружен виндовоз. Включать в меню загрузки?". Я сильно подозреваю, что если в люнихе Вы выполните одну команду *sudo update-grub*, то всё произойдёт автоматически.  Если не поможет, почитайте вот это: https://losst.ru/nastrojka-zagruzchika-grub. Очень подробно всё описано.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, вы уже попасть не можете в linux.

Вам необходим LiveCd с любым дистрибутивом и выполнить указанное в [инструкции.](http://wiki.ayac.ru/ubuntu/vosstanovlenie-grub2-s-livecd)